# Issue with the Firebase database and Page Routing

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am new with flutter and got stuck with an issue. In my code the scenario is:

1. first it authenticate the user through phone and otp verification.
2. After successful verification it must check if the logged in user has profile in the database.
3. If the user profile is available the flag is set to true and then it must route it to the dashboard page

   or
4. If the user profile is not available it must route first to User Profile page to create a profile and then route it to database.

i had written the same condition.On execution as their is user profile in the database still it is routing to User Profile page.

I am also providing the screenshot of the database and the console part.
[image]

Code:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:udharibook/Screens/SignInPage.dart';
import 'package:udharibook/Screens/UserProfile.dart';
import 'package:udharibook/Screens/dashboard.dart';

class AuthService  {
  bool flag = false;
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final DBRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('Users');

  handleAuth(){
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (BuildContext, snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          readData();
          print(flag);
          if(flag ==true)
            return DashboardPage();
          else
            return UserProfile();
        }
        else {
          return SignIn();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  void readData() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    final userid = user.uid;
    DBRef.child(userid).once().then((DataSnapshot data){
      print(userid);
      if(data.value!=null)
        {
          flag =  true;
          print(data.key);
          print(data.value);
        }
      else{
        print('User not found');
        flag = false;
      }
    });
  }

  signOut(){
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }

  signIn(AuthCredential authCreds){
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(authCreds);
  }

  signInWithOTP(smsCode,verId){
    AuthCredential authCreds = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
        verificationId: verId,
        smsCode: smsCode
    );
    signIn(authCreds);
  }
}
```

Comment: There are quite a few possible paths in the code. Since you already seem to have some useful `print` statements in there: what do these print, and which one doesn't print what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to move your flag variable to a global file and then try it. I guess since I dont know what those print statements say.